Why would Chinese ESL learners read FOR/OF alternately?
I noticed that many of my Chinese students read "of" as "for" and vice versa.
I understand that this could be a case of metathesis, but what would be the cause of this? I notice this is consistent across different students, from those who are young to older ones. I can't find a commonality.
Originally, I thought that perhaps Mandarin Chinese doesn't have "of" or "for", but checking some pinyin words I saw that this isn't true.
At least there are Chinese characters for "FO", but not "OF".
I can understand how learners may transpose OF -> FO[R] (on account of precedent in L1), but I don't understand what would cause FO[R] to be read as OF. Is this analogy of some kind?

Sounds to me like they’re just mixing the two words up – a lexical issue, not a phonetic one. Prepositions are complicated, and they rarely map neatly across languages. It’s true that Chinese has no syllables ending in /f/, and inexperienced English students from China often pronounce of (and off) with an extra vowel as /ɒfə/, but pronouncing it like for does not make sense from a phonetic viewpoint. It’s usually easier to remember in words than as prepositions – do they also say ofgive and ofget instead of forgive and forget (’cause I’ve never heard that)?

It is a known fact that students of an L2 make typical mistakes that can generally be traced back to their L1. An easy example: Thanks God, from some Spanish speakers speaking English because in Spanish it's: Gracias a Dios. One would have to speak Chinese really well to answer this.

Visual similarity: In some (lowercase) fonts, "f" and "r" can look similar, especially if read quickly. Here's a simple test, get them to read the same sentence, but written in UPPERCASE. If the problem goes away, that might be the exact cause.
I remember as a child I could read uppercase before lowercase. For people unfamiliar with western script, a similar mechanism may be at play, especially if they are only getting familiar with the script as opposed to their own writing system.

Phonological interference:
While Mandarin Chinese does have words that translate to "of" and "for," the
phonetic structure of these words is quite different from English. The confusion
might stem from the fact that Mandarin doesn't have the /v/ sound found in "of,"
and the /r/ sound in "for" is also not present in standard Mandarin.
Perceptual assimilation:
Chinese speakers might perceive the English sounds /ʌv/ (of) and /ɔr/ or /ər/ (for)
as similar to sounds in their native language, leading to confusion in both
perception and production. The confusion might actually be three way, between the words:
{"of", "or", "for"}

Chinese doesn’t really have a word that corresponds well to of (though it does have some that are roughly equivalent to for). It does have postvocalic [ɹ] as in for, though: it’s a particularly prevalent and ubiquitous feature of the Beijing dialect, but it is used in Standard Mandarin too, to a lesser extent.
